# How do I fild all rows of a 2d array by matching a certain element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

So I have a 2d-array which looks something like this:

```
[
    ["USER1", "2020-03-25 10:41", "hello there I like r/stackoverflow"],
    ["USER2", "2020-03-25 10:42", "I prefer r/programmerhumor"],
    ["USER3", "2020-03-25 10:42", "No, I don't like reddit"]
]
```

And I wish to find each row that contains a message that contain `r/...` in them and return the whole row. The following function is designed to fetch all messages which contain a the keyphrase but I can't figure out how to return the whole row.

```
def get(messages, keyPhrase, column=2):
    r = re.compile("/"+keyPhrase+"/g")
    return list(filter(r.match, [message[column] for message in messages]))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: the regex also does not work and I'd apprectiate help on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the full data array as an iterable and extract the message in the filter function:

```
filter(lambda row: 'r/' in row[column], messages)
```

Comment: see edit. this seems like a good answer but could you help with the regex too? thanks

Comment: Just don't use a regex, use `'r/' in row[column]`.

Comment: I don't get it?

Comment: ik, I don't understand what you mean by "use r/ in row[column]"

Comment: sorry, I get it now, I'm stupid and don't need regex. Thanks for your help!